# bootstrap navbar hamburger dropdown working fine on desktop (all resolutions) but not on mobile device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

My bootstrap and css is functioning fine on desktop browser, but when I go to the site via mobile there are two issues: the navbar isn't as wide as the hamburger toggle and image (regardless of image resize), and the hamburger drop down does not push page contents down--it overlays on contents--this could be fine, but I'd at least need to correct for width of navbar.

Any help is much appreciated

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<css file>" >


</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top" >
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> <img src="{% static "br_email/logo.png" %}" id = "logo"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/"><b>Home</b><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/events/"><b>Events</b></a>
      </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact/"><b>Contact</b></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/profile/"> <b>Profile</b></a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/logout/"> <b>Logout</b></a>

      </span>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  <main role="main" >
         {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </main>


  <div class="content"></div>


  <footer class="footer">


        <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
            <!--&lt;!&ndash; Grid column &ndash;&gt;-->
            <div class="col-12 pt-4">
                <!--&lt;!&ndash;Copyright&ndash;&gt;-->
                <p class="text-center">
                    © 2020 
                     •
                    <a href="/contact/" >
                        <strong> Contact </strong>
                    </a>
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>


  </footer>

   <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
            function loading(){
                $("#loading").show();
                $("#content").hide();
          }
    // ]]>
    </script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($(document).height() > $(window).height()) {
            $('#footer').css('position', 'relative');
        }
});
</script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('a').each(function(){
            if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
                $(this).addClass('active'); $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Navbar related CSS

```
.navbar-fixed-top {height: 40x;} 
.navbar-brand img {height: 40px;}


.navbar-dark{
    background-color: #1a2125;
} 

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #cbd5db;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Comment: put code in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar might resize if it doesn't have a defined width property. I looked through all of your code, and it doesn't look like your navbar has a set width in your css, or in your javascript/jquery/etc. The `<nav>` tag is also a block-level element, meaning that it will take up the entire space of a new row. If you wanted to change the width more easily, you could change it to an inline-block element in css, or use the margin and padding settings. One other mistake I caught is that in your css, at the top of the snippet, you typed 40x instead of 40px (Not sure if you caught that). If you read through your code carefully you may or may not find other mistakes.

Comment: Thanks. the 40x issue actually wasn't an issue, since the class I use is sticky-top. So really, the only height adjustment that worked was the logo. I've found that adjusting navbar height causes the hamburger dropdown to fail on the browser as well (not pushing content down and transparent. 
How can you adjust height and keep the burger dropdown functioning?

Comment: You can set the nav bar height to auto, and adjust the padding/ margin of each item in it to make up the height, which will be easier to do. And as for making it appear and disappear, you can use jQuery to hide the dropdown at the start, and then use a function called slideToggle() to make it slide down (appear) and slide up (disappear). If you want some code to use, ask and I'll create it for you.

Comment: I'm still a bit lost. Adding something dramatic like py-5 does not have any effect on mobile: 
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top py-5" >

Comment: I have found some other things that can be fixed. Try fixing those and see if anything improves: html line 20: replace "br_email/logo.png" with &quot;br_email/logo.png&quot; so the quotation marks will be taken literally, line 41: closing span tag doesn't have opening span tag, possibly delete it. Also, what do you mean by "failing." What exactly is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help, but no luck so far. Here is the site (no domain yet) 18.206.251.142/
The issue is that the navbar does not fit the page on a mobile device. Resizing on the computer works file.

Comment: Loading the page on safari (non mobile) is presenting the same issue